# ng-repeat of a directive and $validators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I have this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F58TTgzKWNVtr9AiOCvz?p=preview). I'm trying to figure out how to allow the user to be able to submit the form despite having an empty "item group" i.e. user is able to submit despite having both `item.foo` and `item.bar` empty but not when one of the form controls isn't empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your template to be:

```
    angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = {};
    $scope.myModel.items = [];
    $scope.myModel.items.push({ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' });
  }).directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        myModel: '=ngModel',
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {

      },
      template: '<ng-form name="add">' + 
        '<input type="text" name="foo" ng-required="myModel.bar" ng-model="myModel.foo" />' +
        '<input type="text" name="bar" ng-required="myModel.foo" ng-model="myModel.bar" />' +
        '</ng-form>',
    }
  })
```

notice the ng-required attribute.

This basically says make foo required when bar is evaluated to true. And make bar required only when foo is evaluated to true

See it live here: http://plnkr.co/edit/pCq8MfgLkZALaWcRLLNz?p=preview